# Easiest way to get an array of random values from another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm wondering what is the easiest/cleanest way to get an array of random values from an array in PHP. It's easy to get an array of random keys but it seems there's not function to get array of values straight away

The easiest way I found out is:

```
$tokens = ['foo', 'bar', '...'];
$randomValues = array_map(function($k) use ($tokens) {
    return $tokens[$k];
}, array_rand($tokens, rand(7, 20)))
```

This returns 7-20 random values from `$tokens` variable. However this looks ugly and is very unclear at first sight what it does.

Comment: since your code is actually working, this looks like a [prime candidate](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to [move](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site#85041) to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: shuffle and then array_slice to get the number of values that you want

Comment: Are sure you aren't getting repeated values ? I would check if the value already exists in the new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to modify your `$tokens` array, you could flip your randomly generated array keys and then use `array_intersect_key`. I think it's a little more readable than the `array_map` method, but I suppose that's fairly subjective.

```
$randomKeys = array_flip(array_rand($tokens, rand(7, 20)));
$randomValues = array_intersect_key($tokens, $randomKeys);
```

If you don't care if `$tokens` is modified, the shuffle\slice method seems very straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Just shuffle and then slice a random number of elements:

```
shuffle($tokens);
$result = array_slice($tokens, 0, rand(7, 20));
```

If you don't want to modify the array then obviously just assign another variable and use that:

```
$temp = $tokens;
```